# Windows Azure Ubuntu Disk read-only

Tags: ubuntu, azure

my Ubuntu Windows Azure VM is constantly putting disk to read-only state.
Here's the log:

```
Jun  5 08:48:33 addagio-web kernel: [253582.732005] hv_storvsc vmbus_0_1: cmd 0x2a     scsi status 0x2 srb status 0x4
Jun  5 08:48:33 addagio-web kernel: [253582.732008] hv_storvsc vmbus_0_1: cmd 0x2a scsi status 0x2 srb status 0x4
Jun  5 08:48:33 addagio-web kernel: [253582.732012] hv_storvsc vmbus_0_1: cmd 0x2a scsi status 0x2 srb status 0x4
Jun  5 08:48:33 addagio-web kernel: [253582.732015] hv_storvsc vmbus_0_1: cmd 0x2a scsi status 0x2 srb status 0x4
Jun  5 08:48:33 addagio-web kernel: [253582.732018] hv_storvsc vmbus_0_1: cmd 0x2a scsi status 0x2 srb status 0x4
Jun  5 08:48:33 addagio-web kernel: [253582.732021] hv_storvsc vmbus_0_1: cmd 0x2a scsi status 0x2 srb status 0x4
Jun  5 08:48:33 addagio-web kernel: [253582.732025] hv_storvsc vmbus_0_1: cmd 0x2a scsi status 0x2 srb status 0x4
Jun  5 08:48:43 addagio-web kernel: [253592.758687] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
Jun  5 08:48:43 addagio-web kernel: [253592.758691] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=invalid driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Jun  5 08:48:43 addagio-web kernel: [253592.758696] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 00 c0 48 01 00 00 08 00
Jun  5 08:48:43 addagio-web kernel: [253592.758704] end_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 12601345
Jun  5 08:48:43 addagio-web kernel: [253592.832032] quiet_error: 12 callbacks suppressed
Jun  5 08:48:43 addagio-web kernel: [253592.832036] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 1573160
Jun  5 08:48:43 addagio-web kernel: [253592.833992] lost page write due to I/O error on sda1
Jun  5 08:48:43 addagio-web kernel: [253592.834012] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  Sense Key : No Sense [current]
Jun  5 08:48:43 addagio-web kernel: [253592.834026] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  Add. Sense: No additional sense information
Jun  5 08:48:43 addagio-web kernel: [253592.834046] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  Sense Key : No Sense [current]
Jun  5 08:48:43 addagio-web kernel: [253592.834062] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  Add. Sense: No additional sense information
Jun  5 08:48:43 addagio-web kernel: [253592.834076] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  Sense Key : No Sense [current]
```

Comment: kernel: [256061.167746] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
kernel: [256061.167751] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=invalid driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
kernel: [256061.167755] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10): 2a 00 00 e5 00 09 00 00 08 00
kernel: [256061.167763] end_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 15007753
kernel: [256061.169963] Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 1873961
kernel: [256061.172048] EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): ext4_end_bio:250: I/O error writing to inode 1235 (offset 8192 size 4096 starting block 1875970)

Answer (score 0):

What kernel version are you using? [This thread](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1157952) suggests that it's specific to using the `storvsc` driver with an ext4 filesystem, and a workaround was added to Linux kernel 3.9-rc1.

So, try a non-ext4 file system, or update your kernel to a later version.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of days ago one of our Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server's root partition become read-only. Shutdown, restart, deallocate did not help, sda1 to / still mounted in read-only mode.
I've reported it to Azure Support. They were really helpful. We figured it out that sda has got some errors. For now I don't know why.

Here is how we fixed it:

#### Repair the file system

> `fsck /dev/sda1`

#### Remount the root partition with read-write option

> `mount -o remount,rw /`

#### Check if it was success

> `mount`

#### Our console messages

> `root@yourserver:~# fsck /dev/sda1`
>
> > `fsck from util-linux 2.27.1`
> >     `e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)`
> >     `cloudimg-rootfs contains a file system with errors, check forced.`
> >     `Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes`
> >     `Deleted inode 2178 has zero dtime.  Fix<y>? yes`
> >     `Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.  Fix<y>? yes`
> >     `Inode 2179 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.`
> >     `Inode 256325 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.`
> >     `Inode 256327 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.`
> >     `Inode 256329 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.`
> >     `Pass 2: Checking directory structure`
> >     `Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity`
> >     `Pass 4: Checking reference counts`
> >     `Pass 5: Checking group summary information`
> >     `Block bitmap differences:  -(46192--46873) -531081 -(6055714--6055716) -(6055720--6055726)`
> >     `Fix<y>? yes`
> >     `Free blocks count wrong for group #1 (3963, counted=4645).`
> >     `Fix<y>? yes`
> >     `Free blocks count wrong for group #16 (25664, counted=25665).`
> >     `Fix<y>? yes`
> >     `Free blocks count wrong for group #184 (15998, counted=16008).`
> >     `Fix<y>? yes`
> >     `Free blocks count wrong (4654888, counted=4655581).`
> >     `Fix<y>? yes`
> >     `Inode bitmap differences:  -(2178--2179) -256325 -256327 -256329`
> >     `Fix<y>? yes`
> >     `Free inodes count wrong for group #0 (39, counted=41).`
> >     `Fix<y>? yes`
> >     `Free inodes count wrong for group #16 (3, counted=6).`
> >     `Fix<y>? yes`
> >     `Directories count wrong for group #16 (2275, counted=2274).`
> >     `Fix<y>? yes`
> >     `Free inodes count wrong (3060151, counted=3060156).`
> >     `Fix<y>? yes`
> >     
> >     `cloudimg-rootfs: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****`
> >     `cloudimg-rootfs: ***** REBOOT LINUX *****`
> >     `cloudimg-rootfs: 699844/3760000 files (0.1% non-contiguous), 3024158/7679739 blocks`
>
> `root@yourserver:~# mount -o remount,rw /`
>
> `root@yourserver:~# mount`
>
> > `...`
> >     `/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard,data=ordered)`